# Top bar should be consistent on all sites... but it's not

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, top-bar

The top bar is showing (again) the suggested edits count and 10K flags count, like it was before.

On Stack Overflow it looks like this: (that's the original color, same as in old top bar)

> [image]

And on this very Meta site:

> [image]

Same top bar. But different colors! Consistency broken.

I've just noticed the suggested edits count on Meta:

> [image]

Black on black, I can see just a floating number - really confusing and out of any context.

In the name of Consistency, can we please have the same color on all sites?

Comment: Dunno. I like them being different - helps with distinguishing what actual site I am on.

Comment: @Oded but the whole point of the new top bar is to have the same design on all sites. Or wasn't it??

Comment: @codehorse well, lots of people think the new top bar is ugly, so it might just fit. :-D

Comment: [Same thing with the suggested edit indicator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213121/make-the-flag-and-suggested-edit-indicator-colors-consistent-across-sites) (which uses `hot` and `hotbg`).

Comment: wait, Stack Overflow has `!important` in its codebase? I think I should be surprised, but having seen nested tables in the design, I'm not (still better than Google's one-letter class names and unparseable AJAX, though).

Comment: @Jan well, there are still times when [this is the right choice](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) so we can't flame the devs just yet. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmm... at least you don't claim tables are sometimes good, just that `!important` is :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Tabular design is the last resort when everything else fails and it's either this or doomsday. ;D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd still prefer `display:table` over actual `<table>`s. Also, I thought that the last resort was `position:javascript` :-)

Comment: @Jan or maybe client side VBScript... or activeX objects... <shudders>

Comment: **cough**... userscript ... **cough**

Comment: @Tim but then other things will break... I see too many reports here about weird problems that turns out to be caused by user scripts.

Comment: I don't really see how injecting a few styles that change colors into a page could break much. Isn't this just asking for the bikeshed to be painted a different color?

Comment: @Tim I disagree. I just hit 2k here, and was presented with a number next to 'review'. At a glance, it looked like it had **no** background, so there was no context at all. Even after using the indicators for over a year on SO, I had to click on meta to find out what it was, because it looks *nothing* the same. To remedy that with a userscript, I would've had to install it *before* I knew it was a problem.

Comment: @Geobits cheers, good points! :)

Comment: Isn't each site supposed to be able to have it's own style guide and what seems different is just styles not the actual design.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just pushed a fix for this. Should be live in the next build.

The top bar will look like this across all sites:

[image]

(That's flags on the left in blue, and pending suggested edits on the right in orange-ish.)

Comment: Ooh, neat, this'll be the first fix I can *remove* from SOUP!

Comment: Should I get my pantone chips to figure out the official color?

Comment: 1337? Must be a fake! Thanks a bunch, my eyes will feel better now when switching between the sites. :-)

Comment: A nice step forward. Are you going to fix the position, while you're at it? The 10k flags and the mod flags are in a different place.

Comment: @Gilles Sure, why not. Will be live in the next build.

Comment: I had [this feature request pending](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213118/move-the-suggested-edit-indicator-to-the-right-of-review) regarding the position. And [please don't pick the MSO suggested edit color](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223085/more-consistent-and-contrasted-color-scheme-for-the-top-bar-indicators), it was the worst of the network.

Comment: One thing about having review privs on only SO is that the color change threw me off; I very nearly posted a question asking whether it was a bug >.>

Comment: @AnnaLear if I may ask, do the colors have any meaning? Did you think of them yourself, or got help from a designer? (I ask because of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224017/152859))

Answer (score 5):

While waiting for the SE folks to fix this properly, I've added a client-side fix for this issue to [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) 1.8.

Basically, what the fix in SOUP does is apply the current SO notification colors to all SE sites.  The choice of the specific colors was somewhat arbitrary, but I chose to go with the SO styles because:

- I had to choose *something*,
- unlike some of the other color schemes, they're at least more or less readable,
- they seem to be the same colors as used on newly graduated SE sites like [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), and
- SO is big and popular enough that, hopefully, the people who designed the top bar paid at least *some* attention to how it looks there.

In any case, I do hope that a proper fix for this issue will arrive soon, so that I can remove the workaround from SOUP.  In the mean time, though, installing SOUP will at least let you *see* the notifications on all sites.