# Move the suggested edit indicator to the right of “review”

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, top-bar

The top bar currently shows, from left to right: the flag indicator (10k only), the suggested edit indicator (2k only), and the “review” and “help” menus.

[image: Stack Overflow indicators]

It's annoying to remember which is which, or which color is which when only one is shown. It would be better if the nature of the indicator could be determined from the position alone.

As a user, I find the flag queue mostly useless — flags have to be processed by a moderator eventually, so it isn't really useful. Conversely, as a moderator, the flag queue is really important: only three of us can deal with it (on most sites), whereas more people can deal with suggested edits. I want the difference between the two numbers to be evident.

Moderators have a “mod” menu to the left of the indicators. The number of flags should be next to that. This makes the following order the obvious solution:

```
mod [flags] review [suggested-edits]
```

(While I'm at it, I'd prefer the moderator inbox, insofar as it's useful at all, to be next to the other mod items. So I'd like it to be to the left of the mod menu.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It's annoying to remember which is which, or which color is which when only one is shown. It would be better if the nature of the indicator could be determined from the position alone.

I agree, although we ultimately went with [a different positioning fix for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212372/top-bar-should-be-consistent-on-all-sites-but-its-not/223003#223003):

[image: indicator colors and positions for 10K users]

Flags are now shown in the same location for diamond moderators and 10k users - to the left of the user profile (and the mod notification diamond).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your positional point.  They should also implement color schemes that are more differentiated.

Comment: Yes, I was just [posting that feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213121/make-the-flag-and-suggested-edit-indicator-colors-consistent-across-sites).