# Make the flag and suggested edit indicator colors consistent across sites

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

This is the flag indicator and the suggested edit indicator on Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow]

This is what they look like on Meta Stack Overflow:

[image: Meta Stack Overflow]

And on Super User:

[image]

This is a flag indicator on sites where it hasn't been customized:

[image: default flag]

This is a suggested edit indicator on sites where it hasn't been customized:

[image: beta suggested edit]

This is Ask Ubuntu. Is that more of a default suggested edit orange or more of a Stack Overflow flag orange?

[image: Ask Ubuntu]

All these indicators have retained their color from back when each site has its own theme in the top bar. But now the top bar is uniform on every site. It doesn't make sense to vary the indicator colors.

Please make the indicator colors uniform across sites. And pick a color with good contrast — the beta suggested edit indicator has pretty bad contrast now, and the SO colors could use a bit more distinction. My preference goes for the default flag color with the SO suggested edit color.