# Why did the position of Flagged Posts box in the Top Bar change?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, top-bar

The position of the orange box that displays the number of active flags in the 10K moderation tools seems to have changed recently.

[image: Screenshot]

The previous position was a perfect spot for it to reside. The new position seems to be a bit out of place. Is this a bug? If not, why was this change made?

Comment: My guess: to separate it from suggested edits and reviews (as it is a totally different thing) as users kept confusing between the two, thinking the 10k flags queue is the review.

Comment: @Sha, I don't think so. I'd expect a user with 10K rep to know the position of the each tool. But in any case, I feel the blank space should be avoided.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: Where? You don't have proof! Do you? *evil laugh* :P

Comment: Space is fine in my opinion, low rep user without many badges will have lots of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It moved to be [consistent with the location of diamond moderator flag count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213118/move-the-suggested-edit-indicator-to-the-right-of-review).