# The suggested edit indicator on beta sites looks like it got unalphafied

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, design, 10k-tools, top-bar

I went over to [my beta site](https://space.stackexchange.com/) today and noticed this fearless messenger in my top bar:

[image]

It's the suggested-edit-pending indicator. However, it looks like someone took all of the 1's opacity away. I don't know what really happened (too lazy to open Chrome's tools), but it sure doesn't look right.

Let's fix it, shall we?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212372/152859 (if they do this, this issue will go away :))