# More consistent and contrasted color scheme for the top bar indicators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, top-bar

The [now unified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212372/top-bar-should-be-consistent-on-all-sites-but-its-not/223003#223003) color scheme for the suggested edit indicator and the moderator/10k flag indicator is:

- red #800000 for suggested edits [image: suggested edit indicator];
- orange #fe7a15 for flags [image: flag indicator and moderator inbox indicator];
- light blue #1e7ecc for the moderator inbox.

I find the contrast of the suggested edit indicator poor. (It's the old color scheme from MSO and I found the contrast poor then.) I also find it inconsistent that the moderator inbox and the moderator flag indicator have completely different colors.

Please switch the flag indicator to the blue shade used for the moderator inbox indicator. This frees orange as a color for suggested edits, which is what it was on most sites before the top bar overhaul. (Alternatively, the fairly similar beige (?) that was used on SO could be used instead.)

I'm not hung on this color choice; what I really want is better contrast for the suggested edit indicator, and the same color for both moderator indicators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solid points all around:

[image]

Comment: Wow! That is a leet flag count ;) But really, this change to blue vastly affected the visitation of the queue on Stack Overflow. It was at 330 when I first noticed the blue, and it is now at 215 only 20 minutes later.. 213 (-2 while writing this comment). Maybe there should be more blue icons.

Answer (score 3):

I also noticed the dark red, and its lack of contrast. But I thought perhaps it is intentionally so.

The red is now used for reviews, the orange is used for flags. I don't know about other SO users but the number of flags is usually at least two orders of magnitude higher than the number of reviews (currently 321 vs 5).

Perhaps they're trying to get more people to do flag resolution?

I always thought it would be a good idea to just merge the two, like: *"here's some stuff that you can do"*.

Comment: 10k flag resolution isn't terribly useful. The flag indicator is always high on SO because almost all flags end up being handled by mods, which takes hours because the moderator flag queue is a lot longer (only a small minority of flags are shown to 10k users). Suggested edits have an average lifetime of a few minutes on SO: they move fast. On other sites, the suggested edit indicator and the flag indicator are lit about as often, and with the suggested edits, you make a difference, whereas the flag indicator is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Migrated [from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223390/214186), written on Feb 27.</sub>

---

I've seen 10k moderator tools colors changing several time in the last days, but please

## STOP IT NOW !!

It is **almost perfect**.

1. `Black` TopBar is great
2. `Red` Inbox Alert is **perfect**
3. `Green` Rep changes is **perfect**
4. `Blue` "Post flagged for moderator attention" indicator is NOW **perfect** (totally integrated in the bar, and absolutely pleasant). A lot better than when it was `orange`.
5. `Brown` "Suggested edit pending for approval" indicator (changed 2-3 times in last two days) is now **good** (can be improved, but it's fine. Yesterday it was *bordeaux* and it was *scary*).

I don't think you can get any closer (especially for points 2,3,4), but I'll be happy to be proven wrong.

Just my 2 cents, keep up the good work :)

[image]

**EDIT**: I'm pretty sure the success of the blue colour is due to the fact that it is very similar to the Bounty indicator (except for the `font-weight`)... someone is playing with our brains :D

Comment: @JanDvorak : about the last picture... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m86ae_e_ptU